# Best way to draw something interactive in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

So, i've created a series of 5 nested circles with HTML5 Canvas. Each of this circles has 16 dots, distributed evenly around the circle.

My idea is for people to be able to drag from one of the 5 dots to the other 5 dots and so on, tracing a line in between the dots that have been connected.

Also, each time the user drags from one dot to the other dot, a callback function should be invoked.

I'm not sure if using HTML Canvas is the right approach for doing this kind of thing, and i'd like to know what would you use to approach this problem, since i'm really stuck on it at the moment.

Below is the code that generates the wheel in [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO80W.png)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.circleCanvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
        // happy drawing from here on
        ctx.lineWidth=1.5;
        var width = window.screen.width;
        var height = window.screen.height;
        var initOuterRadius = width/2-10;
        var cacheRadius = initOuterRadius;
        var wheelCategories = 16;
        var fullAngle = 360;
        //Draws the 5 circles
        for (var i = 1; i<=5; i++){
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(width/2,height/2,cacheRadius,0,2*Math.PI);
          ctx.stroke();

          var angles = 360/wheelCategories;

          var dots = [];
          for (var b = 0; b<=wheelCategories; b++){
            var originX = width/2;
            var originY = height/2;
            var initXCoordinate = originX + cacheRadius * Math.cos(this.getRadians(angles));
            var initYCoordinate = originY + cacheRadius * Math.sin(this.getRadians(angles));
            dots.push({
              xCoord: initXCoordinate,
              yCoord: initYCoordinate,
              radius: cacheRadius
            });
            //Draws the dots
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(initXCoordinate,initYCoordinate,2,0,2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            //Draws the lines 
            if (i == 1){
              ctx.lineWidth=0.6;

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(originX,originY);
              ctx.lineTo(initXCoordinate,initYCoordinate);
              ctx.stroke();
              ctx.lineWidth=1.5;

            }
            angles+=360/wheelCategories;


          }
          cacheRadius-= width/10;
        }

      }
```

Comment: Try this tutorial https://simonsarris.com/making-html5-canvas-useful/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use embedded SVG to solve your problem easier. SVG shapes are managed in the same way as DOM items, and it also has events and styles.

Answer (score 0):

### Canvas and JavaScript, but...

The best way is very dependent on you and your experience and strengths. If you have little to no programing experience but have plenty of HTML/CSS/SVG experience and feel comfortable using them then that is your best option with a little Javascript.

If you are a strong coder and have plenty of experience animating and creating visualizations, with limited HTML/CSS experience then canvas and all Javascript driven.

If you are doing it in part to learn then you should consider what you want to learn.

If you have lots of experience in all then you would not be asking. :)

If you want to know what would be the best practice, from the very limited information you have given and without knowing the target client base / usage type / platform type/s, I hesitantly would recommend a canvas based Javascript driven interface on top of HTML/CSS for semantic context. As this will provide highest performance, most flexibility and behavioural options, and easiest to maintain and modify.